# How to construct MutableList based List in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I hope to construct MutableList a based List b, how can I do in Kotlin?

BTW, Code A is wrong

```
var a:MutableList<MSetting>
var b:List<MSetting>
```

**Code A**

```
var a=mutableListOf(b)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin has a few versions of the `toMutableList()` extension function that should cover you. Check out [the documentation here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html).

Basically, on any `Collection`, `Interable`, typed `Array` or generic `Array`, you can call `.toMutableList()` and it will creat a new MutableList (backed by ArrayList).

So in your code, you can do this (I'm showing types, you can leave them off):

```
var b: List<MSetting> = listOf(...)
var a: MutableList<MSetting> = b.toMutableList()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a generic and needs type information e.g.

```
    var a = mutableListOf<Int>()
```

I tested at https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/

EDIT: I didn't read closely enough, what you want should be a `toMutableList` method.

```
    var b = listOf(2, 3);
    var a = b.toMutableList()
```

Answer (score 1):

it's very easy:

```
val listB = listA?.toMutableList() ?: mutableListOf() // list B = A if (A != null), other wise, B = new empty list
```